# How to change nested Object without mutating it in Redux

Tags: javascript, object, redux

I am pretty new guy to redux.I am little bit confused that how to change this data without mutating it.

my data structure like this

```
    {
      postOwnwerName:"",
        postTags:[],
        photos:[

          {  
            id:dc5c5d7c5s,
            caption:null


            },
             {  
            id:dccccccc5s,
            caption:null


            }





        ],
   }
```

Whent this function fires

this.props.updateCaption(id,caption)

my Reducer should set data according to the id in the data structure without mutating it

```
import * as types from '../Actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    postOwnwerName:"",
    postTags:[],
    photos:[],
};

export default function uploadReducer(state=initialState,action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case types.SETPHOTOSTATE:
            return Object.assign({},state,{ photos:state.photos.concat(action.payload) });
        case types.SETCAPTIONTEXT:

     //this method is not working
            return (
                Object.assign({},state,state.photos.map((data) => {
                    if(data.id == action.payload.id){
                        return Object.assign({},data,{caption:action.payload.caption})
                    }else{
                        return data
                    }
                }))
            )
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the state object has many level it will be difficult to change state without mutating. In those scenario I first copy the state deeply and then make changes to the new state and return new state. See here [Cloning object deeply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). You can try this once.

```
export default function uploadReducer(state=initialState,action) {
  let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
  switch (action.type){
    case types.SETPHOTOSTATE:
       newState.photos.push(action.payload);
       return newState;
    case types.SETCAPTIONTEXT:
       newState.photos.map((data) => {
         if(data.id == action.payload.id){
           data.caption = action.payload.caption;
         }
       });
       return newState;
   default:
     return newState;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx bro Well I am asking a suggestion ,weather Object.assign is good or any library would be better

Comment: You can use spread operator as alternative of Object.assign if you are using es6. I haven't use any library that replaces Object.assign. sorry i have no idea about the library.

Comment: You may also want to read the section on [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) in the Redux docs.