# Update a nested state in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an object in my state as follows:

```
Exercise: {
    id: 1,
    question: '',
    type: '',
    Groups: [
      {
        id: 1,
        category: {
          id: 1,
          value: 'xxx',
          color: 'xxx'
        },
        groupParts: [
          {
            id: 1,
            Index: 7
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            Index: 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

How can I update the value of the **Index** in **id:2** in the reducer?

this is my last try which does not update the value, but creates another section in the current state:

```
case CURRENT_WORD_INDEX_UPDATED: 
  const index=action.selectedWordIndex
  return{...state,index:{...state.Groups[0].groupParts[1].index,in‌​dex},}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Pineda I did edit the question and added my last try

Comment: You can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990993/how-to-change-nested-object-without-mutating-it-in-redux/40991604#40991604). I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of [immutability-helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to update a nested state

```js
import update from 'immutability-helper';

......

case CURRENT_WORD_INDEX_UPDATED: 
  const index=action.selectedWordIndex
  return update(state, {
      Groups: {
         0: {
             groupParts: {
               0: {
                 Index: {
                   $set: index
                 }
               }
             }
         }
      }
  })
```

Comment: Glad to have helped